# Reverse Polish to Infix Notation optimization in java

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, infix-notation

I am trying to solve a programming challange that involves converting reverse polish notation to infix notation. For example:
1 3 + 2 4 5 - + / would be: ((1+3)/(2+(4-5)))
My solution so far does work, but it's not fast enough. So i am looking for any optimization advice.

```
public class betteralgo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = bi.readLine();
        String[] input = line.split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        for(String e:input) {
            switch(e){
                case("+"):
                case("-"):
                case("*"):
                case("/"):
                    String i = stack.pop();
                String k = stack.pop();
                stack.push("(" + k + e + i + ")");
                break;
                default:
                    stack.push(e);
                }
            }
        System.out.println(stack.pop());        
        }       
    }
```

Comment: If the code works this question might be better suited for Code Review

Comment: The answer you've accepted IMHO offers zero speed-up.

Comment: Have you considered parsing the string directly, rather than using `line.split`? Why are you allocating a `StringBuilder` when you don't use it? `StringBuilder` won't help you in this situation. Are you sure this is too slow? How are you measuring the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the quadratic complexity due to working with longer and longer expressions. The solution is to build a tree. Instead of

```
"(" + k + e + i + ")"
```

create a new Node with content `e` and children `k` and `i`. Then a simple pass through the tree allows you to generate any representation (infix, prefix or postfix).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is `O(n)` in time complexity which is fastest possible for this problem I think. But you are not taking advantage of `StringBuilder`, but using time-consuming string concatenation.

Here is the optimised version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line = bi.readLine();
    String[] input = line.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    for(String e:input) {
        switch(e) {
            case("+"):
            case("-"):
            case("*"):
            case("/"):
                String i = stack.pop();
                String k = stack.pop();
                builder.setLength(0);
                builder.append("(");
                builder.append(k).append(e).append(i);
                builder.append(")");
                stack.push(builder.toString());
                break;
            default:
                stack.push(e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stack.pop());  
}
```

Comment: Your optimization is useless as what you did with the `StringBuilder` is exactly what javac does. Manually writing `StringBuilder` concatenations for something like `"(" + k + e + i + ")"` is pointless, you can only gain when carrying the content over loops iterations.

Comment: The complexity is not `O(n)`, it's quadratic as the subexpressions grow with `n`, too.

Comment: If you’re going to use string builder you should be running setLength to clear the cache, allocating a new string builder is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, is this recursive solution any faster?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "1 3 + 2 4 5 - + /";
    List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));      
    String result = build(terms);
    System.out.println(result);
}

static String build(List<String> terms)
{
    String t = terms.remove(terms.size()-1);        
    if("+-/*".indexOf(t) >= 0)
    {
        String op2 = build(terms);
        String op1 = build(terms);
        return "(" + op1 + t + op2 + ")";
    }
    else return t;
}
```

Comment: I doubt it as the `O(n**2)` complexity remains.